# VS2013: How to disable warnings for included header files outside of the project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, warnings, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

In my project I include a header file provided by an external library. With /W3 everything compiles without warnings. However, I want my project to compile cleanly with /W4. That's no problem for my code, but the external header spits out a ton of warnings. I know that I can do something like this:

```
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning( disable: #### )
// include here
#pragma warning( pop )
```

However there is a long list of warnings to disable. Is there a way that I can set the warning level back to /W3 when including this header while still compiling the rest of my code with /W4?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#pragma warning(push, 3)
// include here
#pragma warning(pop)
```

See [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2c8f766e.aspx) for details.

Comment: That did it - thanks! I was looking into what I had to put in warning(warning-specifier : blah ) and didn't know push had an optional second parameter. Much appreciated!